# How to connect another project A to project B as a depedency in java springboot?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, dependencies

I have project B (com.embos) that depends on Project A (com.webfx). I will import project A as a dependency in project B.
This is my pom of project B:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.webfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.webfx</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

When I clean & Build, it is return error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pilahServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'auditTrailService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.webfx.sys.bpm.AuditTrailService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.webfx.sys.bpm.AuditTrailService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> Results:
>   Errors:
>     EmbosApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load  ApplicationCo...

Whereas, in my `PilahServiceImpl` those use `auditTrailService` has been `@Autowired.`

This is my PilahServiceImpl  class:

```
@Service
public class PilahServiceImpl implements PilahService {

    @Autowired
    private PilahRepository repoPilah; 
    @Autowired
    private EmbosRepository repoEmbos;
    @Autowired
    private AuditTrailService auditTrailService;
...
}
```

Why that is happened? Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to inject the dependency for AuditTrailService to ApplicationContext. You'll have to add an instance of AuditTrailService using one of (@Bean, @Component etc.) and a @ComponentScan to scan the class/package where the injection is defined.
I was able to replicate this exception by having the following piece of code:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.webfx.sys.bpm")
public class Example {
    @Autowired
    TestDao dao;
}
```

Adding an @Component annotation on TestDao and a @ComponentScan on Example fixes it.

Comment: Thanks u Sir, I will try it

Answer (score 0):

If you load this bean at the time of server startup itself using configuration. Just add this class in your project and it should start loading the bean.

> Add configuration

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
@Bean
public AuditTrailService auditTrailService() {

    return new AuditTrailService();

}
}
```